# Android Master-Detail Application

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments, android-volley

I am trying to achieve the following:

[image: How my Application will look]

A master-detail two pane flow and the datasource in JSON will be fetched via volley.

But I do not know how to transfer data when `clickEvent()` occured on Master Panel.

I have followed a few tutorials such as http://mobileappdocs.com/android.html and http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Master/Detail_Flow_Tutorial, but I still didn't get that part.

Is it because I am using the default master-detail layout from Android Studio in which only the right (detail) panel is Fragment and the left is not?
Should both the panels need to be Fragments?

I have already done the layouts and I am struggling with the behind Java codes.

**guest_list.xml**

```
<LinearLayout  
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:showDividers="none"
tools:context="awesome.pyie.com.finalapp.GuestListActivity">

<!--
This layout is a two-pane layout for the Guests
master/detail flow.

-->

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/AppDarkGrey">

    <SearchView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/searchView"
    android:background="@color/AppLightGrey"
    android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
    android:queryHint="Search">
    </SearchView>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/guest_list"
    android:name="awesome.pyie.com.finalapp.GuestListFragment"
    android:layout_width="308dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
    tools:context="awesome.pyie.com.finalapp.GuestListActivity"
    tools:listitem="@layout/guest_list_content" />


</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:background="@color/AppLightGrey"
    android:id="@+id/guest_detail_container"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="3">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/add_mid_one"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="onClick"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Add Guest"
        android:textColor="@color/AppWhite"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

**guest_list_content.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/display1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
android:background="@color/AppDarkGrey"> <!--Slave Layout-->

<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/profile_image"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:src="@drawable/logo"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    app:civ_border_width="2dp"
    app:civ_border_color="#83848A"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/id"
    android:textColor="@color/AppWhite"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/profile_image"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:textColor="@color/AppBlue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/text_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/text_margin"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/profile_image"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/profile_image"
    android:layout_marginStart="26dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/AppTime"
    android:text="5:58pm"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<View android:background="@color/AppLightGrey"   android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="1dip" />
```

**MyListActivity** (contains pop up dialog, please ignore that part)

```
package awesome.pyie.com.finalapp;
import android.content.Context;  
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;
import awesome.pyie.com.finalapp.dummy.DummyContent;
import java.util.List;


public class GuestListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private boolean mTwoPane;
final Context context = this;

//API END POINT
public static final String JSON_URL = "*******";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_guest_list);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    //Toolbar title Removed
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

         toolbar.findViewById(R.id.textView2).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    toolbar.findViewById(R.id.addTop).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.add_user_dialog);
            dialog.show();

            //Calculate Device Width and height
            DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
            float dpHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels / displayMetrics.density;
            float dpWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density;

            Window window = dialog.getWindow();
            window.setLayout((int)(dpWidth), (int)((dpHeight)+50));
               window.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

            TextView cancelText = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

            cancelText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
        }
    });


    View recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.guest_list);
    assert recyclerView != null;
    setupRecyclerView((RecyclerView) recyclerView);

    if (findViewById(R.id.guest_detail_container) != null) {
        // The detail container view will be present only in the
        // large-screen layouts (res/values-w900dp).
        // If this view is present, then the
        // activity should be in two-pane mode.
        mTwoPane = true;
        toolbar.findViewById(R.id.textView2).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }


}

private void setupRecyclerView(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter(DummyContent.ITEMS));
}

public class SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter
        extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private final List<DummyContent.DummyItem> mValues;

    public SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter(List<DummyContent.DummyItem> items) {
        mValues = items;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.guest_list_content, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mItem = mValues.get(position);
        holder.mIdView.setText(mValues.get(position).id);
        holder.mContentView.setText(mValues.get(position).content);

        final ImageView imageView =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        final TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mTwoPane) {
                    //Code Here
                    imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    //Ends Here
                    Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
                    arguments.putString(GuestDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, holder.mItem.id);
                    GuestDetailFragment fragment = new GuestDetailFragment();
                    fragment.setArguments(arguments);
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.guest_detail_container, fragment)
                            .commit();
                } else {
                    Context context = v.getContext();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, GuestDetailActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(GuestDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, holder.mItem.id);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });


        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            //Start new list activity
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.add_user_dialog);
                dialog.show();

                //Calculate Device Width and height
                DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
                float dpHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels / displayMetrics.density;
                float dpWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density;

                Window window = dialog.getWindow();
                window.setLayout((int)(dpWidth), (int)((dpHeight)+50));

           window.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

                TextView cancelText = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

                cancelText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

            }
        });        //Add Button Function - will display the add page


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mValues.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public final View mView;
        public final TextView mIdView;
        public final TextView mContentView;
        public DummyContent.DummyItem mItem;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mView = view;
            mIdView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id);
            mContentView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.content);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return super.toString() + " '" + mContentView.getText() + "'";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As per the tutorial link you are following, you should have an ListActivity class which handles displaying both the master and detail fragments.

If you follow the template, there should be an onItemSelected() callback in the listactivity, which will get which item is selected, inside this method pass the selected information to the detailfragment and render accordingly

Comment: Can you post your java code? And what is it exactly you want to do? Do you want to find out which item was clicked in your master panel?

Comment: @Sammy T,
I want to grab data from a URL, put them in a array list or custom list. Populate them on the list panel. And when items in master panel is selected, the detail panel will get updated. Thanks

Comment: Ok, but you've got to narrow that down. You're passing a bundle to the fragment with the click which is good but is the click working? Are you getting the right information when you retrieve the bundle in the fragment?

Comment: @SammyT,Thanks for helping me out.
I managed to solved the problem. Will update the codes soon.